# CypherError trying to use an escaped json as string

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to running an `ON CREATE SET` with the following values:

```
"ON CREATE SET 
    node.stat_val = "[{\\"id\\":\\"20a80637-f1d5-40d7-968a-a1b44da5afe0\\",\\"title\\":\\"Checklist Adesão\\",\\"isPersonalList\\":true,\\"isSharedList\\":false,\\"settings\\":{\\"preventSolve\\":false,\\"dontAllowChanges\\":false,\\"tags_setting\\":[\\"check_adesao\\"]},\\"tasks\\":[{\\"title\\":\\"teste1\\",\\"id\\":\\"1f255631-cfd6-4c44-9d63-5b29952d7b33\\"}]}]", 
    node.stat_name = 'max', 
    node.start_epoch = '1577398480', 
    node.end_epoch = '1577398490', 
    node.published_tag = 'unique_tag',
    node.publisher_last_updated_epoch_ms = timestamp()"
```

But I'm facing an error because the encoded json:

> neobolt.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: Invalid input 'd': expected 'n/N' or 's/S' (line 2, column 38 (offset: 136))

What is the proper way to escape json content?

Answer (score 0):

You're escaping the slash, this should work:

```
ON CREATE SET 
    node.stat_val = "[{\"id\":\"20a80637-f1d5-40d7-968a-a1b44da5afe0\",\"title\":\"Checklist Adesão\",\"isPersonalList\":true,\"isSharedList\":false,\"settings\":{\"preventSolve\":false,\"dontAllowChanges\":false,\"tags_setting\":[\"check_adesao\"]},\"tasks\":[{\"title\":\"teste1\",\"id\":\"1f255631-cfd6-4c44-9d63-5b29952d7b33\"}]}]", 
    node.stat_name = 'max', 
    node.start_epoch = '1577398480', 
    node.end_epoch = '1577398490', 
    node.published_tag = 'unique_tag',
    node.publisher_last_updated_epoch_ms = timestamp()
```